# LVM not able to be resized or checked with resize2fs and e2fsck

Tags: linux, partition, lvm, resize2fs, e2fsck

I extended an lvm from the terminal in system rescue live CD using the commands:

```
# pvcreate /dev/sda7
# vgextend fedora /dev/sda7   
# lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/fedora/root
```

The above worked but when I try to check the LV file system or resize it I get the following errors:

```
# e2fsck -f /dev/fedora/root

e2fsck: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/fedora/root
Possibly non-existent device?

# resize2fs /dev/fedora/root
open: No such file or directory while opening /dev/fedora/root
```

Do I have to activate or mount the volume before I run those commands? I didn't change the name of the volume group.

[image: Gparted live picture]

#### UPDATE

Resolved by simply adding command provided by Hauke Laging before `resize2fs` or `e2fsck`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough that a LV exists on the PV, it must also be active for being used i.e. the device mapper device (`/dev/mapper/fedora-root`) must be created:

```
lvchange -ay fedora/root
```

or

```
vgchange -ay fedora
```

Comment: thanks very much @Hauke Laging, the first command worked flawlessly. I wanted to confirm if I have to deactivate the logical volume using `lvchange -an fedora/root` before rebooting?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia No, there is no need for deactivation. Unmounting the filesystem is enough.

Comment: thanks for confirming @Hauke Laging. When I run `lsblk` in the live CD it doesn't show the file system as mounted. Should I unmount with `umount /dev/mapper/fedora-root` or right click and select deactivate in GParted?